# Which number are interchanged from sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search, sorting

I have an array of Sorted integers. We can use binary search to find an element . 
Now if one element of sorted array is interchanged with another element.
What would be the best way to find the interchanged element?

Comment: in essence, you do a binary search and find which element sent you the wrong way

Comment: Travers your array and compare adjacent elements.

Comment: @nem with a binary search you may never encounter the misplaced element. or you could encounter it, but not see that it is misplaced.

Comment: I you need both elements that were switched, start traversing the array from both the start and end positions, going forward and backward respectively, until you find elements that are out of order. Those are the switched elements.

Comment: Keep in mind that, if there are duplicate elements in the array, there may be no noticeable difference in the array and finding the swap would be impossible.

Comment: If there is an error, one element not sorted, searches and inserts can go wrong. If you pick values at some indices and do binary searches you still have no guarantee that if the search uses the wrong value, that some midpoint in a range will be the wrong value.

Comment: @Shaded That reminds me of the Steven Wright joke: "Someone broke into my house and replaced everything with exact replicas."

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I totally understand the question, anyway If you don't know the both elements, and as the interchange has no "rule". it seems you need at least o(n) to find the interchanged element.  (by a simple loop).

If you do know one element (one of the pair) and want to find the other pair. simply binary search the one pair you know, you will find the other in his place.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the only method to find such element is regular linear search. You cannot do faster because you basically not searching particular element, you are searching the position when some property is violated (in this case the ordering). As you don't know anything that can help you skip checking some positions you basically need to check all of them. So it will be O(n) — regular linear search.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to do linear search, and worst-case time is linear. But best case time could be log n.

Once you find the first displaced element, you'll know that integer. Therefore, you can do a binary descent to find the position that it should be in. So basically, if one of the two mismatches occurs early, you will save time